# 2 different arrays, one allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm solving a scheduling problem and I'm creating an instance generator.
I have an issue - arrays t1, t2, t3 point the same memory cell, as a result all arrays, after allocation, have the same data.
Here's my code

(...)

```
int **t1;
    t1= new int*[1];
    t1[1]=new int[2];

    int **t2;
    t2= new int*[1];
    t2[1]=new int[2];

    int **t3;
    t3= new int*[1];
    t3[1]=new int[2];

    for (int s=0; s<20; s++ )
    {

        for (int w=0; w<3; w++)
        {
            time[w]=(rand() % 200) +1;
            machine[w]= (rand() % 3) +1;
            if (w>0)
                    while (machine[w]==machine[w-1] || machine[w]==machine[0])
                        {
                            machine[w]= (rand() % 3) +1;
                        }

        }

        t1[0][0]=machine[0];
        t1[0][1]=time[0];
        t2[0][0]=machine[1];
        t2[0][1]=time[1];
        t3[0][0]=machine[2];
        t3[0][1]=time[2];
```

(...)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `std::vector<int>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t1= new int*[1];
```

allocates an array of one pointer.

```
t1[1]=new int[2];
```

writes to the second element of this one element array.  This results in undefined behaviour.  In your case, it sounds like `&t1==&t2[1]`, causing you to overwrite the address of a previous allocation each time you create a new array.

You should write to the first element of the array instead

```
t1[0]=new int[2];
// ^
```

If use of C-style arrays isn't a requirement of an assignment, you could implement arrays of `int` more easily using `std::vector<int>`.